# My word count programme in python wont work

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, for-loop, printing

In this programme I was making a word count but its not working for some reason and I dont know why

```
#For this Programme I was trying to find out the word count and sentence count in a given text
sentence= ("I hope to fuck this works. It would mean great things to me.")
sent_count=0
word_count=sentence.split()

# here it counts the words in the senctence
numberofwords=len(word_count)
for ch in sentence:
    if ch== ".":
       sent_count +=1

# everything looks pefrect I dont know why it is not working
print("There are",numberofwords "words in this paragraph")
print("There are",sent_count"in this paragraph")
```

Comment: try printing `ch` in the for loop. You'll see that `ch` is never equal to ".".

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "its not working"? Is it not showing any output? Is it showing output, but the wrong kind? Is it running forever? Is it crashing with an error message and stack trace?

Comment: BTW, try to use meaningful names. `word_count` is not the word counter in your program but a list of words, so `words` would have been a far better name.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the comma (`,`) at the end of the variables you inserted in `print`:

```
print("There are", numberofwords, "words in this paragraph")
```